# metadata of pivotted field

Tags: sql, types, datatable, pivot

I have a complicated question based on a complicated database setup.

I have a table that has fieldId, objectId, fieldValue.
Each object has many rows in this table - one row for each field.

Example - there are fields for firstname, dob, weight, height,school etc

An object `(id:1)` can have the following rows:

```
1.1.'john'
1.2.'march-31-2000'
1.3.155
1.4.60
1.5.'ps 176'
```

I have a grid that will show a column for each field and a row for each object - 
the column names will be firstName, dob, weight, height, school
and there will be rows for all objects in my db

I used a pivot to get this data -

something like -

```
SELECT *
  FROM #temp123
 PIVOT (
          MAX(fieldValue)
          FOR [Variable] IN ([firstName],[dob],[weight],[height],[school])
       ) AS p
```

This is working well for displaying the data. However, now it's time to add sorting to my grid. I want the int column to sort like an int (101>99), the date column to display like a date (1/1/2016>12/31/2015)

How can I accomplish this.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you have to explain better about those INT and DATE field that only appears on your question at the end unlinked with everything else. Can you explain it better? A data sample about it would be good too.

Comment: Dear StackOverflow, 

Your community consists of some very knowledgeable and helpful programmers, like Shnugo quoted below, and unfortunately, some not very knowledgeable bored ppl who like to ruin many questions with irrelevant and negative comments. I posted a very clear question, with examples and details, knowledgeable programmers were able to give me a lot of help. See below. The latter category of programmers just try to give negative irrelevant feedback. For example - "Maybe you have to explain better about those INT and DATE field". The ints and date fields have in fact been

Comment: explained in detail. Do you want me to explain why student A weighs 250 pounds and student B 125. Do you want me to add in details that student A eats more than student B? I'm beginning to find these irrelevant comments babyish and ridiculous. I believe you should do something about them.

Comment: No need to be rude here. We all are here to help, always remember that. Your question got closed by five people that read it and find it hard to understand. It may be explained on **your** point of view. Here we don't assume that one has experience or not. We just want to be sure about the data so we can provide good and accurate answers. As for your "I posted a very clear question" here is an example of what is a good and well formated SQL question: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/460557 If you still feel that we  were wrong on closing your question you can open a case on...

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com There is the place for you to open a complaint.

Answer (score 1):

This might be the solution for you:

```
CREATE TABLE #EntityAttributValue (entityID INT, Attribute VARCHAR(100),Value VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO #EntityAttributValue VALUES
 (1,'BirthDate','2000-04-01')
,(1,'Size','1.72')
,(1,'FirstName','John')
,(1,'LastName','Doe')
,(2,'BirthDate','1990-04-01')
,(2,'Size','1.81')
,(2,'FirstName','Jane')
,(2,'LastName','Miller')
,(3,'BirthDate','1980-05-01')
,(3,'FirstName','Hugo')
,(3,'LastName','Boss');

DECLARE @columns VARCHAR(MAX)=
(
    SELECT STUFF(
    (
    SELECT DISTINCT ',[' + Attribute + ']' 
    FROM #EntityAttributValue
    FOR XML PATH('')
    ),1,1,'')

);

DECLARE @query VARCHAR(MAX)=
'SELECT p.*
FROM
(
    SELECT *
    FROM #EntityAttributValue
) AS tbl
PIVOT
(
    MIN(Value) FOR Attribute IN(' + @columns + ')
) AS p';

--The column's list might be generated from metadata (dictionary attrib/type)
DECLARE @Wrapped VARCHAR(MAX)=
';WITH MyCTE AS (' +  @query + ')
SELECT  entityID
       ,CAST(BirthDate AS DATE) AS BirthDate
       ,FirstName
       ,LastName
       ,CAST(Size AS FLOAT) AS Size
FROM MyCTE';

EXEC (@Wrapped);

GO
DROP TABLE #EntityAttributValue;
```

#### This was the former answer

Name-Value-Pairs (or Entity-Attribute-Value tables [EAV]) are in general something one should not do... Here is an article (and you'll find a lot more!) describing why: http://www.sturnus.co.uk/performance/2008-07/the-curse-of-the-name-value-pair/

If you have to stick to this design, there is a solution using `CASE` with `GROUP BY`, but you must be sure, that your values will be casted correctly (Be especially carefull with date-time values!):

```
DECLARE @EntityAttributValue TABLE(entityID INT, Attribute VARCHAR(100),Value VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @EntityAttributValue VALUES
 (1,'BirthDate','2000-04-01')
,(1,'Size','1.72')
,(1,'FirstName','John')
,(1,'LastName','Doe')
,(2,'BirthDate','1990-04-01')
,(2,'Size','1.81')
,(2,'FirstName','Jane')
,(2,'LastName','Miller')
,(3,'BirthDate','1980-05-01')
,(3,'FirstName','Hugo')
,(3,'LastName','Boss');

SELECT eav.entityID
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN eav.Attribute='FirstName' THEN eav.Value ELSE NULL END) AS FirstName
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN eav.Attribute='LastName' THEN eav.Value ELSE NULL END) AS LastName
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN eav.Attribute='BirthDate' THEN CAST(eav.Value AS DATE) ELSE NULL END) AS Birtdate
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN eav.Attribute='Size' THEN CAST(eav.Value AS FLOAT) ELSE NULL END) AS Size
FROM @EntityAttributValue AS eav
GROUP BY eav.entityID
```

Comment: I understand your comment for a standard query, but I dont know how to do this in a pivot -   SELECT *
  FROM #temp123
 PIVOT (
          MAX(fieldValue)--case statement here not working
          FOR [Variable] IN ([firstName],[dob],[weight],[height],[school])
       ) AS p

Comment: @thewhiz No, this is instead of the `PIVOT` The pivot will not allow you to type this. There might be a chance to wrap your full query (either CTE or sub-select) and type out the full column list in your outer most `SELECT` and do the casts there...

Comment: oh i see. Im dynamically generating this query, i can have many columns. do you know if pivot is more efficient than this? or vice versa? I definitely like the clean pivot syntax, but maybe this approach is what i'll need to take

Comment: @thewhiz, As far as I know this "old fashioned pivot" is better in performance... If this solves your problem it would be very kind to tick the acceptance check below the vote counter, thx!

Comment: thanks. I'll do just that, but can you pls clarify one more thing - if i want to stick with the old fashioned pivot for better performance - should i maybe get a dictionary of fieldID - fieldType and for the fields that are not text, cast the columns then?

Comment: @thewhiz, sorry, I've put this in very misleading words actually... The approach with `GROUP BY` and an aggregate function like `MAX` or `SUM` is the "old fashioned way" of doing pivot queries. The `PIVOT` syntax came later and does not allow different types, neither do the pivot on more than one column. So the `GROUP BY` should perform better. If you want to stick with the existing query you can sourround the full query with anohter query and cast all fields there.

Comment: can you give more details of that pls? that is what i dont know how to do

Comment: @thewhiz You are creating the pivot query dynamically, don't you?

Comment: yes. so which query do i surround by what?

Comment: thanks. i upped your answer. it wont be displayed yet bec thewhiz is new on stackoverflow and doesnt have a high enough reputation yet

Comment: Off-topic: you should not try to quote names yourself by enclosing them between rectangular brackets (`[]`) manually. You should be using [`QUOTENAME`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-be/library/ms176114.aspx) (without arguments). Consider a table name `Alfa][Beta` or column name `Theta[]Quo` and watch your statements fail. `QUOTENAME` will properly quote the rectangular brackets within the name correctly and enclose the name in rectangular brackets for you. Not that I think having brackets in a column name is a good idea... but it happens.